# Obter o número de dependentes de um funcionário

Tags: mysql, select

Estou tentando fazer uma pesquisa entre 3 tabelas:
Funcionario,Dependentes,Funcionario_has_Dependentes;
Quero fazer a pesquisa em que mostre o número de dependentes de cada funcionário.
Eu fiz o seguinte:

```
    select dependente.*,funcionarios.*  
      from funcionarios f,dependente d,dependente_has_funcionarios df 
      where f.Matricula = df.Matricula and  
      df.Dependente_idDependente = d.idDependente;
```

Mas ele não funcionou.
PS:Matricula é PK de funcionário.

Answer (score 6):

Ola, Reproduzi seu cenário aqui! e montei o que talvez você esteja querendo:

```
CREATE TABLE Funcionario
(
    Id                    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nome                  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Dependente
(
    Id                    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FuncionarioId         INT NOT NULL,
    Nome                  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES Funcionario(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Dependente_Has_Funcionario 
(
    Id                    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FuncionarioId         INT NOT NULL,
    DependenteId          INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);

insert into Funcionario (Id,Nome) values ('101','Rodrigo Mendez');
insert into Funcionario (Id,Nome) values ('102','Marco Ciciliano');
insert into Funcionario (Id,Nome) values ('103','Paulo Guerra');
insert into Funcionario (Id,Nome) values ('104','Renato Teixeira');
insert into Funcionario (Id,Nome) values ('105','Antonio Marcos');

insert into Dependente (Id,FuncionarioId,Nome) values ('101','101','Mauricio Filho');
insert into Dependente (Id,FuncionarioId,Nome) values ('102','101','Arnaldo Filho');
insert into Dependente (Id,FuncionarioId,Nome) values ('103','102','Jenival Filho');
insert into Dependente (Id,FuncionarioId,Nome) values ('104','102','Walter Filho');
insert into Dependente (Id,FuncionarioId,Nome) values ('105','105','Nataly Filho');

insert into Dependente_Has_Funcionario (Id,FuncionarioId,DependenteId) values ('101','101','101');
insert into Dependente_Has_Funcionario (Id,FuncionarioId,DependenteId) values ('102','101','102');
insert into Dependente_Has_Funcionario (Id,FuncionarioId,DependenteId) values ('103','102','103');
```

Você pode fazer usando 2 tabelas com a clausula "GROUP BY" com um "COUNT" entre Funcionário e Dependente:
<sub>Veja no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbfe8/1)</sub>

```
SELECT
    a.Nome,
    COUNT(*) Dependentes
FROM 
    Funcionario a,
    Dependente b
WHERE 
    a.id = b.FuncionarioId     
GROUP BY 
    a.Nome;
```

ou pelo que percebi usando a terceira tabela que é Funcionario relacionada com a tabela 'Dependente_Has_Funcionario'
<sub>Veja no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbfe8/2)</sub>

```
SELECT
    a.Nome,
    COUNT(*) Dependentes
FROM 
    Funcionario a,
    Dependente_Has_Funcionario b    
WHERE 
    a.id = b.FuncionarioId   
GROUP BY 
    a.Nome;
```

Espero ter ajudado!
Oks!

Comment: Editei a sua resposta adicionando *links* para o *SQLFidlle* onde o resultado das *querys* podem ser visualizadas.

Answer (score 2):

Você não especificou o que não funciona, mas sugiro alterar sua query para utilizar a cláusula `JOIN` (`LEFT JOIN` nesse caso pois um funcionário pode não possuir dependentes).

```
SELECT d.*, f.*
FROM funcionarios f
LEFT JOIN dependente_has_funcionarios df ON df.Matricula = f.Matricula
LEFT JOIN dependente d on df.Dependente_idDependente = d.idDependente
```

Também sugiro se quer saber apenas o número de dependentes, que especifique as colunas que quer utilizar e utilize `COUNT`.

```
SELECT f.Matricula, COUNT(df.*) As QtdDependetes
FROM funcionarios f
LEFT JOIN dependente_has_funcionarios df ON df.Matricula = f.Matricula
LEFT JOIN dependente d on df.Dependente_idDependente = d.idDependente
GROUP BY f.Matricula
```